# Highchart.js and AngularJS after navigation some chart does not load

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am currently facing a problem. I have a HTML page which contains multiple div to load highcharts. Same page have all the jquery script.

I am using angularJS to route the page. Index page, Chart1Page and Chart2Page. When i am loading chart1page 1st time all charts load but if i come back from chart2page to chart1page some charts does not load. Below code is one of the chart which not load. If i replace with some other chart like pie the result is same. Do i need to check the sequence?

```
<script>
function freecapacity() {
            $(function () {
                // Set up the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'freecapacity',
                        type: 'column',
                        margin: 75

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Free Capacity'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            depth: 25
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'S', 'D', 'DD', 'PD']
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6]
                    }]
                });
            });
        }

        freecapacity();
</script>
<html>
<div class="row">

    <h5 class="form-control" style="background-color:#D2D7D3"><label>Hub and GSA Information</label></h5>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 small">
        <div class="form-control" style="height: 350px;" id="freecapacity"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 small">
        <div class="form-control" style="height: 350px;" id="gsanomination"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</html
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the JS console? Also, is `freecapacity` method called when you go back to the page_1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the Angularjs directive for Highcharts: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Than set up the Highchart object in the view controller instead of using script tags in the html file.

Comment: thanks @euparkeria, can I just keep existing code as is and load other charts as couple of charts still working fine with out having angularjs directive.